# Hiding menu items in TreeViewer

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

I am trying to hide/unhide a submenu item (menumanager) from the context (popup menu)
when specific node is selected/not selected in the tree.

Although the setVisible methods triggered as expected it doesn't effect.

The Code:

```
TreeViewer tViewer;

tViewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL);

tViewer.setLabelProvider(new WorkbenchLabelProvider());
tViewer.setContentProvider(new BaseWorkbenchContentProvider());
tViewer.setInput(viewFactory.getInstance().getRoot());      


final MenuManager menuMain = new MenuManager("Main",null);
menuMain.add(mActionClose);


MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu", "contextMenu");
menuManager.add(menuMain);


menuManager.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {           
    public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {             

        //Get the selected node in tree
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) tViewer.getSelection();

        if (!selection.isEmpty()) { //If something selected
            NNodeBase ob = (NNodeBase) selection.getFirstElement(); //Get the base class of node                                    

            if (!(ob instanceof NTMModel)) {                        
                menuMain.setVisible(false);                     
            }
            else
                menuMain.setVisible(true);                      
        }
    }
});


Menu menu = menuManager.createContextMenu(tViewer.getControl());
tViewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the manager to recreate the menu before it is shown:

```
menuManager.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
```

Then, in `menuAboutToShow()` you add the items, testing the condition you need:

```
if ((ob instanceof NTMModel)) {
    menuManager.add(mActionClose);
} else {
    // don't show the menu item
}
```

You don't need `menuMain` anymore.

Comment: 1)what do you mean I don't need menuMain? this manager acts as sub-menu, it has a few menu items inside!
2)in my real menu structure, i have another items beside the menuMain, RemoveAllWhenShown will require me to rebuild every thing every time

Comment: Yes, the menu will be rebuilt everytime it is shown. If `menuMain`  is a submenu, then it is ok.

Comment: but why can't I just set the visability?

Comment: I think you should call `menuManager.update(true);`  (see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825162/hiding-menu-items-in-jface-menumanager-and-treviewer/7832794#7832794) I didn't test it.

Comment: I tried that also...
is it possible to "disable" the MenuManager, so the this sub-menu appear as grayed out? 
I can only set setEnabled(false) on action and not on the menumanager